# Unable to Read Files in Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  etcd:
    container_name: 'etcd'
    image: 'quay.io/coreos/etcd'
    command: >
      etcd -name etcd
      -advertise-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
      -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
      -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://127.0.0.1:2380
      -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://etcd:2379/version"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      robotrader:

  kontrol:
    container_name: 'kontrol'
    env_file: 'variables.env'
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    volumes:
      - '/certs:/certs'
    ports:
      - '6000:6000'
    depends_on:
      - 'etcd'
    networks:
      robotrader:

  mongo:
    container_name: 'mongo'
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - '/var/lib/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb'
    networks:
      robotrader:

networks:
  robotrader:
```

... and here is the `Dockerfile` used to build `kontrol`:

```
FROM golang:1.8.3 as builder
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
RUN go get -d github.com/koding/kite
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/koding/kite
RUN ${GOPATH}/bin/dep ensure
RUN go install ./kontrol/kontrol
RUN mv ${GOPATH}/bin/kontrol /tmp

FROM busybox
ENV APP_HOME /opt/robotrader
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
RUN mkdir /certs
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
COPY --from=builder /tmp/kontrol .
ENTRYPOINT ["./kontrol", "-initial"]
CMD ["./kontrol"]
```

Finally when I issue the command...

```
sudo -E docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up
```

... both `etcd` and `mongo` start successfully, whereas `kontrol` fails with the following error:

```
kontrol    | 2018/06/21 20:11:14 cannot read public key file: open "/certs/key_pub.pem": no such file or directory
```

If I log into the container..

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name j3d-test --entrypoint sh j3d
```

... and look at folder `/certs`, the files are there:

```
ls -la /certs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1679 Jun 21 21:11 key.pem
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  451 Jun 21 21:11 key_pub.pem
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this command:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name j3d-test --entrypoint sh j3d
```

You are not "logging into the container". You are creating a *new* container, and you are looking at the contents of `/certs` on the underlying image.  However, in your `docker-compose.yaml` you have:

```
kontrol:
  [...]
  volumes:
    - '/certs:/certs'
  [...]
```

You have configured a bind mount from `$PWD/certs` onto the `/certs`
directory in your container.  What does your local `certs` directory
contain?